# Streetview placeholder is here, but Pegman is missing

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I've integrate the googlemaps api
but Pegman is missing from the streetview little white square (bottom right)

[image: google map]([![Googlemap]

I've notice that some div that hold the pegman icon in googlemaps code have height and width equal at 0px
what can I do to fix that ?

Here's a sample of how I called and initiate my map

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```

Here's my map component :

```
<div class="map-box" id="map" #map></div>
```

with css.js looking like

```
.map-box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and how I create it :

```
    var ownPos = {lat: -4.85, lng: 2.35};
    this.mapDisplay = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: ownPos, streetViewControl: true});
```

Comment: Probably a CSS problem.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: That is very minimal, but it doesn't allow me to reproduce your issue (and you didn't include any of the required CSS (which is likely where the issue is))

Comment: @geocodezip Here I added the CSS and even the index.html where I call the API, it's really all what I do, (beside placing markers when clicking a button) nothing more so ... yep ...

Comment: As I said, the posted code doesn't reproduce your issue. It is missing at least this: `html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}` to show the map; and when I add that, it shows the map **and** the pegman.  ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mt6nad17/3/)).  Therefore while it might be minimal, it is not complete (and you didn't verify it reproduces the issue)

Comment: '/deep/' was deprecated as of 2017. I have the same issue and the solution still left a blank white square where Pegman should be. Is there a solution without using '/deep/'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixing of wrappers' height solved the same bug

```css
agm-map {
  height: 425px;
  & /deep/ .gm-svpc { //dispayed pegman's icon on map
    div {
      height: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and solved it with some CSS:

```
/* Force position to show pegman */
.gm-svpc div img {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: Nice! But there is one drawback with this fix: When the pegman icon is hovered, the tilted pegman symbol is smaller than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* there are actually two `<div>`s, with the 2nd one actually holding the symbol */
.gm-svpc > div:last-of-type {
  /* same dimensions as symbol child element */
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```